# FragmentPageAdapter without FragmentActivity

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, pageviews

Can I use FragmentPageAdapter without FragmentActivity?

My PageView is in a Fragment, not an activity.

Comment: Made the question simpler and easier to read, so that users are more likely to quickly understand what you want and know if they can help.

Comment: thx dude... its correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you use the

```
android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

from support library v13. You can use native Fragment and Activity instead of v4.Fragment and FragmentActivity.

In that case, you can contructor the Adapter like this

```
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

You should have a adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter.

```
public class TestFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TestFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new YourFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And new a instance of TestFragmentPagerAdapter,

```
TestFragmentPagerAdapter testFragmentPagerAdapter = new TestFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Is possible to put getChildFragmentManager to constuctor instead of getSupportFragmentManager?

Comment: Yes, in fragment you should put `getChildFragmentManager()` to the constructor of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. While in `FragmentActivity`, use `getSupportFragmentManage()`

Comment: new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); right?
But when I use that codes, i got error... The Constructor pageAdapter is undefined... like this.

Comment: it is right. did you extend  `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Could you show me some sample code to use getChildFragmentManager?

Comment: Nope. I made new Instance in Fragment